# Is it possible to fetch all data from a DE without a mutual field?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Currently I use `LookUpRows('some_DE', 'AMPKEY', '&')` to fetch all data from a DE, where every single record has an `AMPKEY` field with `&` as the value. Is it possible to perform the same in MC another way?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible inside AMPScript without the method you described in your question. There are some alternatives that can be used in a non-sendable context though.

In SSJS you can use the core library to use the [Rows.Retrieve()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsRetrieve.htm) method, which can retrieve all rows (up to 2500 record max) inside of a DE.

example:

```
var  birthdayDE = DataExtension.Init("birthdayDE");
var data = birthdayDE.Rows.Retrieve();
```

You can also use the API object of [DataExtensionObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextensionobject.htm) to gather all the rows as well.

Sample SOAP Envelope:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Header>
 <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
 <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24440876" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
 <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
 <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>
 </wsse:UsernameToken>
 </wsse:Security>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
 <RetrieveRequest>
 <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Example DE]</ObjectType>
 <Properties>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Properties>
 <Properties>CUSTOMER_ID</Properties>
 <Properties>FIRST_NAME</Properties>
 <Properties>SITE_GROUP</Properties>
 <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
 <Property>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Property>
 <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
 <Value>acruz@example.com</Value>
 </Filter>
 </RetrieveRequest>
 </RetrieveRequestMsg>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I've read that documentation, however Im running into a problem because I cannot access `_Sent` dataview using SSJS (without knowing its external key). The way I understand it, system dataviews dont have external keys, which is why I was trying to use ampscript.. however dataviews dont have a field for all records as I've described in my question, so I cannot use ampscript. Is there another way? Is it possible to access dataviews with SSJS?

Comment: That was not the question you asked. That is a completely different question. Please create a new question for this inquiry.

Comment: [Here it is](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235497/how-to-reference-system-dataview-with-ssjs), thank you.